# how to get the selectedIndex of many comboBox in the form?

Tags: c#, combobox

I need to get the `SelectedIndex` of many `ComboBox` instances of the Form. I've tried with:

```
internal static void getComboSelectedIndex(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        getComboSelectedIndex(c);
        if (c is ComboBox)
        {
            int i = ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

and calling this method with:  `getComboSelectedIndex(this);`
but it doesn't work. It returns Always -1 for every `comboBox` in the form.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the `comboBox` instances actually have an item selected?  `SelectedIndex` will return `-1` to indicate there is not a selected item.

Answer (score 1):

without recursion after the first iteration of the WindowsForm the loop is exited. With the recursion the foreach loop iterates between every combobox but returns selectedindex = -1 for every combobox.

The method that I have copied from another question:

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
```

{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast();

```
return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
                          .Concat(controls)
                          .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
```

}

works very well but it returns only the number of the combobox of the windowsForm, but I am not able to change it to return the selectedIndexes because I don't know linq controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following codes:

```
internal static void getComboSelectedIndex(Control control)
    {
        List<ComboBox> comboBoxes = new List<ComboBox>();

        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            getComboSelectedIndex(c);

            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox curretComboBox = ((ComboBox)c);

                if (curretComboBox.SelectedIndex > -1) // should be greater than -1 not 0 because first index of comboboxes is 0 not 1
                comboBoxes.Add(curretComboBox);
            }
        }
        var orderedList = comboBoxes.OrderBy(item => item.TabIndex).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < orderedList.Count; i++)
        {
            ComboBox _current = orderedList[i];

            MessageBox.Show("selected index of " + _current.Name + " is " + _current.SelectedIndex.ToString() + " / TabIndex: " + _current.TabIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very GOOD work Lujska !  I have made many tests with your last TabIndexed method and now it works good just as I needed. Thank you, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using recursive function in foreach loop?

This codes below should return selected index of all comboboxes which is in the current form:

```
internal static void getComboSelectedIndex(Control control)
{
foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
    {
        int i = ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex;
MessageBox.Show("selected index of "+ c.name + " is "+ i.ToString());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you AGB, you are correct, I have so modified my method:

```
    internal static void getComboSelectedIndex(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            getComboSelectedIndex(c);
            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                int i = ((ComboBox)c).SelectedIndex;
                if (i > 0) MessageBox.Show("selected index of " + c.Name + " is " + i.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

and now it works. I didn't know that -1 indicate combobox with "not selected item". Now I have another little question: Is it possible to get the selectedIndex of the comboboxes sequetianly following theirs TabIndex ?